# Restringir Apenas Aulas de um Curso via Controller Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

Bom, nem eu sei como perguntar direito por que faz menos de uma semana que comecei a estudar laravel. Por favor peço compreenção de todos, desde já grato!

Meu caso é o seguinte: Eu tenho uma tabela de Cursos e uma Tabela de Aulas, onde o relacionamento é 1:N, Um curso pode ter muitas Aulas mas a Aula so pode pertencer a um curso. Segue minhas migrations:

**Tabela Cursos:**

```
Schema::create('cursos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();;
    $table->bigInteger('categoria_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('dono_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('nome');
    $table->string('descricao');
    $table->float('valor');
    $table->string('imagem');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Tabela Aulas:**

```
Schema::create('aulas', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->bigIncrements('id');
   $table->bigInteger('curso_id')->unsigned();
   $table->string('nome');
   $table->text('descricao');
   $table->time('duracao');
   $table->string('link');
   $table->timestamps();
});
```

**ForeignKey:**

```
Schema::table('aulas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('curso_id')->references('id')->on('cursos');
});
```

Fiz também os relacionamento via Model.

**Model Curso:**

```
[...]
    public function aulas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('app\Aula', 'curso_id', 'id');
    }
```

**Model Aula:**

```
[...]
public function curso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('app\Curso', 'curso_id', 'id');
}
```

Eu queria fazer uma rota que seria algo do tipo ".../user/**curso/CursoID/aula/AulaID**" onde passo tanto o id do curso quanto o id da aula. Agora chegando na parte onde me perco, como ficaria a ou as funções da minha Controller de uma forma que ao ir para a proxima aula apenas o id da aula mude, e que se por exemplo por algum motivo remoto o usuario for manualmente no link e colocar uma id de uma aula que não pertence ao curso em que esta ativo no momento, a model retorne a ultima id valida?

No caso dessa rota estar sendo muito "complicada", qual seria uma rota que atingiria minha ideia?

Eu tentei da seguinte forma:

**Rota:**

```
Route::prefix('usuario')->namespace('Usuario')->group(function () {
        [...]
        Route::prefix('curso')->group(function(){
            Route::get('/{cursoid}/aula/{aulaid}', 'CursosController@aulas')->name('curso.aula');
        });
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
public function aulas($cursoid,$aulaid)
    {
        $curso = Curso::findOrFail($cursoid);
        $aula = Aula::findOrFail($aulaid);
        $aulas = $curso->aulas;
        return view('usuario.aula',compact('curso','aulas','aula'));
    }
```

E embora eu tenha chegado na rota desejada ela simplismente não limita a apenas as aulas do curso ativo. 
Faltando qualquer coisa, so pedir que eu acrescento em um edit ou tiro duvida nos comentarios!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É que tu não fazes a verificação se a aula que tu busca é do curso.

```
// pega o curso já com a relação das aulas dele
$curso = Curso::with(['aulas' => function($query) use ($aulaid) {
    $query->where('id', $aulaid);
}])->findOrFail($cursoid);
```

Então verifica se existe a aula e pega ela.

$aula = null;

```
if($curso->aulas->isNotEmpty())
{
    // faça isso porque 1 N retorna uma colection
    // Se fosse pegar um curso atravez de uma aula retornaria um objeto Curso
    $aula = $curso->aulas->first();
```

}

=========================================================

Da uma lida em relatioships e collections... Da pra fazer de vários meios.